# Getting first time-In and last time-Out covering the following day based on a date Collection using linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, time-and-attendance

I am having a problem getting structured First Entry and Last Entry on the Biometric reading when it exceeds the following day when the user time out. But if the time in and time out is on the same day i can get it formatted the way i want..

here is my code:

```
     IEnumerable<biometric> dtrs = new List<biometric>()
        {
            new biometric{Id = 1, InOut = 0, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,8,0,0)},
            new biometric{Id = 2, InOut = 0, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,8,0,5)},
            new biometric{Id = 3, InOut = 0, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,8,1,0)},
            new biometric{Id = 4, InOut = 0, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,8,2,0)},

           //here is my problem getting this paired to
            new biometric{Id = 5, InOut = 0, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,18,0,0)},

            new biometric{Id = 1, InOut = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,18,0,0)},
            new biometric{Id = 2, InOut = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,17,5,5)},
            new biometric{Id = 3, InOut = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,17,5,10)},
            new biometric{Id = 4, InOut = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,17,10,0)},

            //this Entry here
            new biometric{Id = 5, InOut = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,6,3,0,0)},
        };

        var asd = dtrs.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.DateTime.Date }, (key, group) => new
        {
            Key1 = key.Date,
            Key2 = key.Id,
            Result = group.OrderBy(a => a.DateTime).ToList()
        })
         //checks if the grouping result has one timein and 1 timeout or more
        .Where(a => a.Result.Where(z => z.InOut == 1).Count() >= 1 && a.Result.Where(z => z.InOut == 0).Count() >= 1)
        .Select(a => new dtr() { employeeId = a.Key2, TimeIn = a.Result.FirstOrDefault(b => b.InOut == 1).DateTime, TimeOut = a.Result.LastOrDefault(c => c.InOut == 0).DateTime });



     private class biometric
      {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public int InOut { get; set; }
      }

      private class dtr
      {
        public int employeeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeIn { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOut { get; set; }
       }
```

I want to pair this
**new biometric{Id = 5, InOut = 0, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,18,0,0)},**

to this
**new biometric{Id = 5, InOut = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,6,3,0,0)},**

any workaround or suggestions??

Comment: Can't you just group by `Id` and order by `InOut`?

Comment: no.. were getting it per day and on the following day as well

Answer (score 1):

```
    var asd3 =  from d1 in dtrs
                join d2 in dtrs on d1.Id equals d2.Id
                where d1.InOut ==0 
                   && d2.InOut == 1 
                   && d2.DateTime > d1.DateTime 
                   && d2.DateTime.AddHours(-18) < d1.DateTime 
                orderby d1.DateTime.Date, d1.Id
                select new dtr {employeeId = d1.Id,
                                TimeIn=d1.DateTime,
                                TimeOut= d2.DateTime};
```

I added a second days worth of data, to assure that the filtering was right.  This assume that no one works more than 18 hours in a day.  Assuming that most people work a standard 8 hours, that could be set as high as 31 hours.

```
employeeId TimeIn                         TimeOut
1         05/05/2013 08:00:00.000         05/05/2013 18:00:00.000 
2         05/05/2013 08:00:05.000         05/05/2013 17:05:05.000 
3         05/05/2013 08:01:00.000         05/05/2013 17:05:10.000 
4         05/05/2013 08:02:00.000         05/05/2013 17:10:00.000 
5         05/05/2013 18:00:00.000         05/06/2013 03:00:00.000 
1         05/06/2013 08:00:00.000         05/06/2013 18:00:00.000 
2         05/06/2013 08:00:05.000         05/06/2013 17:05:05.000 
3         05/06/2013 08:01:00.000         05/06/2013 17:05:10.000 
4         05/06/2013 08:02:00.000         05/06/2013 17:10:00.000 
5         05/06/2013 18:00:00.000         05/07/2013 03:00:00.000
```

Also, as a side note, your original code contain `a.Result.Where(z => z.InOut == 1).Count() >= 1`.  That could be reduced to `a.Result.Any(z => z.InOut == 1)` which, beside being be concise & easier to read, would probably execute faster.

UPDATE:
Adding these two records (Employee 1 goes to lunch)

```
        new biometric{Id = 1, InOut = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,12,0,0)},
        new biometric{Id = 1, InOut = 0, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,13,0,1)},


var sorted = dtrs.OrderBy (d =>d.Id).ThenBy (d =>d.DateTime ).ToList();

var zipped = sorted.Where (d =>d.InOut==0 ).Zip(sorted.Where (s =>s.InOut==1),
                (i,o)=>{
                        Debug.Assert(i.Id == o.Id);
                        return new dtr
                    {
                        employeeId = i.Id, 
                        TimeIn=i.DateTime,
                        TimeOut= o.DateTime
                    };
                }).OrderBy (d =>d.TimeIn);
zipped.Dump();
```

Comment: adding this line 

new biometric{Id = 1, InOut = 0, DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,8,0,1)}, 

it Creates 6 Pairs in having same date as time in but just a minute later so cannot be marked as answered

Comment: That would require the person to have clocked in twice without leaving.  I can't be responsible if you input data in invalid.

Comment: i got a workaround with that.. I grouped the answer again in what if tried

Comment: Now, if you had data where people checked in and out multiple times a day (say, leaving for lunch), then you have a different problem, which isn't suited to handling as a set using LINQ.  You're best off forming two lists, one for in times, and one for out times, sorted by id and date, and walking through them.

Comment: well we must always consider that the end users are dumb enough to log in twice :)

Comment: yup im looking into that... Sorting two list. but im worrying on couple thousand sets of records performance using linq